# WCF & IIS - This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-10

I'm running IIS 10 on Windows 10 Pro, and hosting a WCF RESTful service.

For some reason I'm getting "This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset." ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. 
[image]

I'm able to debug and step though my code till the very end successfully so I know the service is executing fine without any errors when the URL is hit.

But for some reason IIS is not displaying the results / json and is showing this error

I have spent over a day on this. Any advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you [enable tracing for WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing)  to get more information

Comment: I am having a similar problem. did you resolve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552134/strange-iis-wcf-web-service-issue